# Get record type developer name in Flow instead of RecordTypeID

Tags: visual-workflow, process-builder, case, emailmessage

I am creating a flow on EmailMessage object. I want to retrieve the record type name in the flow instead of RecordTypeID.

[image]

Is there any way to get the name instead of ID?

Comment: You need another getRecord element before this element to retrieve the record type record.

Answer (score 2):

As of the Summer 22 release, you can now reference the triggering Record's RecordType DeveloperName in Entry Criteria by using the new Entry Criteria Formula builder. In an Entry Criteria formula, you can traverse up parent lookup relationship fields, including the RecordType field with something like this:

`$Record.RecordType.DeveloperName = 'My_RecordType_DeveloperName'`

Previously, alternatives were to use a formula field that returns the RecordType's DeveloperName (which wouldn't resolve in a Before Save On Create Flow) or a Decision.

Comment: This is great! Formulae make it even easier in many other scenarios.

Comment: @jeff kranz can we also use related lookup records in formula evaluates to true to check values of fields from parent record?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an option to get the RecordType.Name on the getRecord element for the case object.

I would suggest you to have the Record type validations in a "***Decision***" Element just after the get record element.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the the [UnofficialSF Execute SOQL custom Flow component](https://unofficialsf.com/a-graphical-soql-query-builder-for-flow/)

This site has a terrific collection of useful flow elements that wrap functionality that otherwise would require you to write either Javascript or an invocable apex method

You can pass an arbitrary SOQL string like

```
 SELECT Id, Subject FROM Case WHERE RecordType.Name = 'Foo'
```

Relationship queries are supported. There are some prerequisite components you need to first install so read the Installation Steps carefully.